# $_POST input not reaching handler page

Tags: php, html

i have a form it has a hidden input called id, when it submits it goes to a handler page and that filters other forms and decides what to do through a switch statement, this form is supposed to call a class function through the handler and send the id to the parameter of the function, but the id input is not reaching the handler, i checked by echo $id and nothing shows up so i'm sure the id is not sent to the function parameter, where is the error i can't find it i spent two hours looking for it.

the form

```
function showPassengerRides($db)
{
    
    //fetching the data from database
    $row=$stmt->fetchAll();

   if($row)   
   { 
        
      foreach ($row as $stmt):?>
        
        <form action="rideHandler.php" method="POST" class="rides" >
         //echoing data from database
            
          <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?=$stmt['id'] ?>" />
           //i echoed here and it worked, so i'm sure the problem is not from the SQL statement 

          <button class="delete-button" name="formSubmit" value="delete">Delete</button>
                    
       </form>               
                   
                    
 <?php }
```

the handler page

```
switch ($_POST['formSubmit']) {
    
case 'delete':

$id = $_POST['id'];
   //i echoed here but nothing showed up
    $obj = new databaseUpdate();
    $obj->deleteReservation($id, $db);
break;

}
```

Comment: Try some more debugging: e.g. put `var_dump($_POST);` as the first line of the handler file and see what is actually being sent to it

Comment: it showed me this : array (size=2)
  'id' => string '24' (length=2)
  'formSubmit' => string 'delete' (length=18), so it reached the handler, but i can't figure why it's not echoing or sending to the function

Comment: Does the `switch` execute?  Does it enter the delete `case`?  Lot's of questions you can answer with echos.